# jboss failing to start the context

Tags: jboss

i am getting below error when i start the jboss, i am running my application in eclipse jobss, even i tried to run from terminal i am getting the same error.

is the below server issue or application configuration issue?

```
20:22:24,053 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.3.Final-redhat-1
20:22:29,362 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.1.5.Final-redhat-1
20:22:29,455 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-19) starting
20:22:30,470 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found md-edrs.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called md-edrs.war.dodeploy
20:22:30,495 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-11) XNIO Version 3.0.10.GA-redhat-1
20:22:30,496 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
20:22:30,501 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-11) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.10.GA-redhat-1
20:22:30,524 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-11) JBoss Remoting version (unknown)
20:22:30,544 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
20:22:30,543 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS010153: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
20:22:30,548 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
20:22:30,550 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
20:22:30,550 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
20:22:30,564 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 35) JBAS012605: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main, 1.2]
20:22:30,571 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.19.SP8-redhat-1
20:22:30,604 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-11) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.0.26.Final-redhat-1)
20:22:30,627 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
20:22:30,630 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
20:22:30,686 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
20:22:30,836 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
20:22:30,847 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
20:22:30,932 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (version 4.0)
20:22:31,032 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-11) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.3.0.Final-redhat-3
20:22:31,211 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /Users/raja/JBOSS/jboss-eap-6.3-1/standalone/deployments
20:22:31,214 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "md-edrs.war" (runtime-name: "md-edrs.war")
20:22:31,232 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
20:22:31,233 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-9) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:4447
20:22:34,225 INFO  [org.jboss.as.pojo] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS017000: Found legacy bean/pojo namespace: urn:jboss:bean-deployer:2.0 - might be missing some xml features (potential exceptions).
20:22:34,876 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component edu.ucdavis.dmm.validation.validator.PasswordResetRequestValidator due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
20:22:34,876 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component edu.ucdavis.dmm.validation.validator.PasswordResetValidator due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
20:22:35,014 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS016012: Deployment deployment "md-edrs.war" contains CDI annotations but beans.xml was not found.
20:22:35,972 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) JBAS018210: Register web context: /md-edrs
20:22:35,989 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/md-edrs]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
20:22:35,994 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/jdbc/mdedrsDS2]
20:22:35,994 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/jdbc/mdedrsDS]
20:22:35,993 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/jdbc/mdedrsDS3]
20:22:36,004 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/md-edrs]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
20:22:37,295 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/md-edrs]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) JBWEB000287: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'configurationHelper' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/web-application-config.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'build.number'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:209) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:220) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:84) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:656) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:161) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:59) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:94) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)

20:22:37,333 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.28-jbossorg-2  for context '/md-edrs'
20:22:38,194 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.1.Final-redhat-1
20:22:39,010 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) JBWEB001103: Error detected during context /md-edrs start, will stop it
20:22:39,011 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/md-edrs]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
20:22:39,013 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./md-edrs: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./md-edrs: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:166)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:59)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:94)
    ... 6 more

20:22:39,045 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS018559: Deployed "md-edrs.war" (runtime-name : "md-edrs.war")
20:22:39,045 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./md-edrs: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./md-edrs: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context

20:22:39,050 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
20:22:39,050 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
20:22:39,050 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-19) started (with errors) in 15361ms - Started 292 of 334 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 60 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
20:42:05,936 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-14) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment md-edrs.war (runtime-name: md-edrs.war) in 26ms
20:42:05,938 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "md-edrs.war" (runtime-name: "md-edrs.war")
20:42:07,591 INFO  [org.jboss.as.pojo] (MSC service thread 1-9) JBAS017000: Found legacy bean/pojo namespace: urn:jboss:bean-deployer:2.0 - might be missing some xml features (potential exceptions).
20:42:08,055 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-12) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component edu.ucdavis.dmm.validation.validator.PasswordResetRequestValidator due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
20:42:08,056 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-12) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component edu.ucdavis.dmm.validation.validator.PasswordResetValidator due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
20:42:08,188 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-12) JBAS016012: Deployment deployment "md-edrs.war" contains CDI annotations but beans.xml was not found.
20:42:08,197 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) JBAS018210: Register web context: /md-edrs
20:42:08,204 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/md-edrs]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
20:42:08,211 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/md-edrs]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
20:42:09,197 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/md-edrs]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) JBWEB000287: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'configurationHelper' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/web-application-config.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'build.number'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:209) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:220) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:84) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:656) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:161) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:59) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:94) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)

20:42:09,200 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.28-jbossorg-2  for context '/md-edrs'
20:42:10,295 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) JBWEB001103: Error detected during context /md-edrs start, will stop it
20:42:10,296 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/md-edrs]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
20:42:10,297 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./md-edrs: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./md-edrs: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:166)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:59)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:94)
    ... 6 more

20:42:10,340 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment md-edrs.war (runtime-name: md-edrs.war) in 38ms
20:42:10,343 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.SimpleCachingHeadersPageCachingFilter".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.BindTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EscapeBodyTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.HtmlEscapeTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.NestedPathTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.ThemeTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.TransformTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.UrlTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.ButtonTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.ErrorsTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.HiddenInputTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionsTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.PasswordInputTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.RadioButtonsTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.TextareaTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./md-edrs.realm (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."md-edrs.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./md-edrs
      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./md-edrs

20:42:37,471 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core] (MSC service thread 1-9) JBWEB001079: Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/] has not been started
20:42:37,475 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010409: Unbound data source [java:/jdbc/mdedrsDS]
20:42:37,475 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010409: Unbound data source [java:/jdbc/mdedrsDS2]
20:42:37,477 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010409: Unbound data source [java:/jdbc/mdedrsDS3]
20:42:38,477 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBWEB003075: Coyote HTTP/1.1 pausing on: http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
20:42:38,478 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBWEB003077: Coyote HTTP/1.1 stopping on : http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
20:42:38,486 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015950: JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-19) stopped in 1012ms
```

can somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

```
20:22:37,295 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/md-edrs]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) JBWEB000287: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'configurationHelper' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/web-application-config.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'build.number'
```

Provide value for 'build.number' in `web-application-config.xml` or at run time.